# select maximum value and minimal date from it's corresponding dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
ClientId | CalculationDate | TransactedAmount |
  1         13/02/2015              3
  1         14/02/2015              3
  2         14/02/2015              5
  3         15/03/2015              6
  2         15/03/2015              5
```

As a result I want table which contains ClientId and minimal Months passed since 
maximum amount were transacted for each clientId.
How can i do that?

Comment: *'minimal Months passed since maximum amount'* is it based on today? Can you also put the expected output for above so its easy to understand

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: maybe it's just me: but i am not able to understand your question

Comment: platform is Microsoft sql.

Comment: humpty dumpty, yes , it is based on today.

Comment: output would befor this exmaple output should be
1 --- 14/02/2015
2  --- 15/03/2015
3 ----15/03/2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ClientId , MaxAmount.TransactedAmount , DATEDIFF(MONTH,MaxAmount.CalculationDate ,getdate())
   FROM TABLENAME T1
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 TransactedAmount ,CalculationDate 
                    FROM TABLENAME T2
                    WHERE  T1.ClientId = T2.ClientId 
                    ORDER BY TransactedAmount DESC) MaxAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Window Function like Row_Nummber() we can achieve the same

```
;With cte(ClientId , CalculationDate , TransactedAmount )
AS
(
SELECT 1,'13/02/2015',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'14/02/2015',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'14/02/2015',5 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'15/03/2015',6 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'15/03/2015',5 
)
SELECT ClientId , CalculationDate,TransactedAmount From
(
SELECT ClientId , CalculationDate ,MAX(TransactedAmount)OVER(Partition by ClientId Order by  CalculationDate) As TransactedAmount ,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition by ClientId Order by  CalculationDate) AS RNo From cte
)Dt 
WHERE Dt.RNo=1
```